# Multiple cloud projects publishing to the same web role

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-storage, azure-web-roles, webrole

Is it possible to have multiple cloud projects independently publish to one web role?

For example, cloud **project A's** `ServiceDefinition.csdef` would contain:

```
  <WebRole name="SomeWebRole" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="WebA">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
  </WebRole>
```

And **project B**:

```
  <WebRole name="SomeWebRole" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="WebB">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint2" endpointName="Endpoint2" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint2" protocol="http" port="81" />
    </Endpoints>
  </WebRole>
```

They have different `<Site>` names and are bound to different endpoints (port 80 and port 81).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ... no, you can't deploy from different cloud projects to a single cloud service ... because you need to describe the whole service (including its websites) in a single csdef file that must belong to a single cloud project.

Answer (score 0):

Sure! You can publish multiple web projects to a single web role and bound them to different ports or host headers.

Here more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433110.aspx

Comment: But can these separate sites be deployed from different cloud projects?